# regex - remove partial text from duplicate strings

Tags: regex, notepad++

with some hassle i've come up with the following reg ex: `(?m)(XXX).*\R(?s).*?\K\1` where XXX is the text i am selecting in the duplicate string (in this case `(?m)(#  .*).*\R(?s).*?\K\1`).

When I go for finds everything is ok but somehow Notepad++ gets stuck when I am trying to apply it and failing replaces. Sometimes find also fails too. any help about?

E.g.:

```
#Tfr.msg.FoldCleanup#   Folder Cleanup
#Tfr.msg.FoldCleanup#   Folder Cleanup
```

I need to select and change everything after '# ' of every second duplicate string.

update: i've tried it here (https://regex101.com/r/WQXFy6/42) and it works correctly. but it goes completely nothing with N++...

Comment: Could you give more examples and expected result?

Comment: also i need a similar regex to append a character in every first string of the 2 duplicates if it's possible. thanks, please!

Comment: @Toto https://imgur.com/R0VzV0J

Answer (score 0):

I've found out the correct regex to my second question and works flawlessly.

Find:

```
^(.*?)$\s+?^(?=.*^\1$)
```

replace with:

```
!$0
```

Answer (score -1):

I also have found out myself the correct regex for my first question:

```
(#  .*)\r(?s).*?
```